# vs2003 : c# can not build visual studio solution

Tags: c#

I get latest from source control and can not build my visual studio solution. I get the following error:

Cannot copy assembly 'XYZ' to file 'C:\myfolder\bin\Debug\XYZ.dll'.  The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

I have rebooted the machine but nothing seems to work. please help.

Comment: According to "handle" tool, VS DEV Env itself is holding on to that DLL. So how do I build via VS.net and avoid this error?

Comment: What source control system you use? I'm using Borland star team, and have the same problem, checking out project file but ST holds folder read only, So I have to manually check off read only state. I think your version control do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine what other process is holding the DLL open - my bet is that it is Visual Studio itself.  Try closing down any open form Design windows (or all code/design windows in VS.Net for that matter) and see if you still get the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) tool to determine what process is using that file:

```
handle XYZ.dll
```

From there, you can figure out what started the process and why it's using the file.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever i've seen that error, it was because the program i was trying to compile was still running.  You may want to check and make sure any debug sessions are stopped (not just paused, but stopped completely), and that your program doesn't appear in the Task manager under the "Processes" tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the build configuration from Debug to Release  and try compiling again.

Answer (score 0):

let's try a simple solution.  The DLL in your bin directory is likely marked as Read-Only.  Visual studio doesn't check out the DLLs from the BIN directory when you check out source files.  So if you keep the binaries in source safe then you need to manually check them out or manually take off the read-only flag in the directory.